# Как вернуть качество картинки в процессе анимации? SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

Столкнулся с проблемой ухудшения качества картинки при использовании анимации. Понимая, что далеко не первый, кто с этим столкивается - загуглил и понял, что SVG сможет решить мою проблему. Сначала изменил просто формат самого изображения на `.svg`, но не помогло => нужно именно через тег `<svg>...<svg>`. Проблема в том, что даже не знаю, можно ли с помощью этого тега сделать то, что мне нужно (картинку прикрепил) и как это сделать...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код анимации, на всякий случай:

```
 .orderOnlineB {
    position: fixed;
    animation: animOrderOnlineB 6s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animOrderOnlineB {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
    }

    50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg);
    }

    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого нужно конвертировать растровую картинку в векторную. Можно ручками, можно онлаин https://convertio.co/ru/jpg-svg/

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Распространенная проблема. Как уже писали выше что нужно конвертировать в svg. Кстати не обязательно вставлять инлайн как теги `<svg>...</svg>`, можно как `<img stc="our_image.svg">`

Теперь вопрос как растр превратить в вектор, есть очень много путей(ai, corel), но самый бесплатный figma + плагин image tracer. И как всегда чем выше в разрешении картинка тем она точнее. На выходе вектор может быть "не совсем" круглым и поэтому надо его поместить в frame(ctrl + alt + g) и выровнять (В правой панели будут всем знакомые значки )

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]